# VB ToolStripControlHost remove Text property

Tags: vb.net, properties, user-controls, toolstrip

I have a class that allows ToolStrip to have a NumericUpDown. I added a properties (Value, Minimum and Maximum). It is working but I want to remove the Text property since I added the Value property. Is there a way to do this?

[Please see image where you can see the designer properties](https://ibb.co/cFmN1d)

Below is the class

```
<Windows.Forms.Design.ToolStripItemDesignerAvailabilityAttribute(Windows.Forms.Design.ToolStripItemDesignerAvailability.ToolStrip), DebuggerStepThrough()>
Public Class ToolStripNumericUpDown
    Inherits Windows.Forms.ToolStripControlHost

    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New(New System.Windows.Forms.NumericUpDown())
    End Sub

    Public ReadOnly Property ToolStripNumericUpDownControl() As Windows.Forms.NumericUpDown
        Get
            Return TryCast(Control, Windows.Forms.NumericUpDown)
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Property Value() As Long
        Get
            Return ToolStripNumericUpDownControl.Value
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Long)
            ToolStripNumericUpDownControl.Value = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property Minimum() As Long
        Get
            Return ToolStripNumericUpDownControl.Minimum
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Long)
            ToolStripNumericUpDownControl.Minimum = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property Maximum() As Long
        Get
            Return ToolStripNumericUpDownControl.Maximum
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Long)
            ToolStripNumericUpDownControl.Maximum = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Protected Overrides Sub OnSubscribeControlEvents(ByVal c As Windows.Forms.Control)
        MyBase.OnSubscribeControlEvents(c)
        AddHandler DirectCast(c, Windows.Forms.NumericUpDown).ValueChanged, AddressOf OnValueChanged
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub OnUnsubscribeControlEvents(ByVal c As Windows.Forms.Control)
        MyBase.OnUnsubscribeControlEvents(c)
        RemoveHandler DirectCast(c, Windows.Forms.NumericUpDown).ValueChanged, AddressOf OnValueChanged
    End Sub

    Public Event ValueChanged As EventHandler

    Private Sub OnValueChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        RaiseEvent ValueChanged(Me, e)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: You can't remove the property altogether but you can make it less visible. That's exactly what is done in the `NumericUpDown` control itself. Read the documentation for that the `NumericUpDown.Text` property and you'll se how it's done using attributes.

Comment: By the way, given that the `ToolStripTextBox` has a `TextBox` property and the `ToolStripComboBox` has a `ComboBox` property, wouldn't it be more appropriate for your `ToolStripNumericUpDownControl` property to be named `NumericUpDown`?

Comment: Thank you. Documentation really helps. I added some line of code and Text property is now not showing on Property Box. Not sure what you mean on your second comment, I named the class ToolStripNumericUpDown same with other tool strip controls.


<ComponentModel.EditorBrowsable(System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Never), ComponentModel.Browsable(False), ComponentModel.BindableAttribute(False)>
    Public Shadows Property Text As String